# Rate of change of momentum of a fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

Consider a volume G that is the volume containing the same number of fluid particles, that evolves with time

The total momentum of the collective volume is obviously

$$\vec{P} = \iiint_{G} \rho \vec{V} dv$$

The rate of change of momentum of these particles is therefore

$$\frac{d}{dt}\iiint_{G} \rho \vec{V} dv$$

My proffessor then states that 'since the mass of any single fluid particles is constant with respect to time, $\rho dv$ is a constant,we can bring the time differential inside to give'

$$\iiint_{G} \frac{D\vec{V}}{Dt} \rho dv$$

Can someone explain this more mathematically to me? Surely there is a more complicated proof involving specific time dependant volume limits etc. Also isn't this only strictly true for incompressable flows? Where the material derivative of mass density is equal to zero?

Comment: $\frac{d\rho}{dt}=0$ follows from the continuity equation. I think your professor either forgot, or assumed you knew, that because the velocity/divergence term (in the continuity equation) must vanish for _incompressible flows_ the only term that remains is the derivative, which must therefore equal zero (yes, it is only valid for incompressible flows).

Comment: How do we treat the boundary term in the integral? Since a change in volume changes the quantity. However since we assume the volume encloses the 'same' particles, can we show this to be zero?

Comment: This result was used in my proffessors derivation of the navier stokes equations and so is valid for compressible fluids. If the material derivative is zero surely this is not true. I assume the boundary term of the integral and the second term in the expansion cancel out to give the result given

Comment: _Since a change in volume changes the quantity_ What change in volume? This is for incompressible flows, otherwise $\frac{d\rho}{dt}\ne0$. Also Jensen, it may help if you show this complete proof in the question. Cheers.

Comment: After doing some more research, the term is correct and does not require that it is incompressable. The volume in question is a volume that encloses the same fluid parcels, ie one that evolves with time. My mistake is using the material derivative straight away, when I should have been using the regular derivative. Reynolds transport theorem can be used and the condition of the problem is one such that v_{b} = v  where v is the fluid velocity, this models the volume as changing in accordance to the  fluid motion. It can be shown that the boundary term of the integral, and the other term

Comment: Add together in such a way that the material derivative is the resultant function only. This does not require the condition of incompressable flow and is a valid way of deriving the navier stokes equations which are valid for compressible flows. This can be seen here https://cfdisraelblog.wordpress.com/2022/01/10/from-reynolds-transport-theorem-to-navier-cauchy-to-navier-stokes-voyage-part-i/

Comment: I have added a full derivation of this in my edit. There is no need for the fluid to be incompressable

Answer (score 1):

From reynolds transport theorem for a moving volume boundary in accordance to fluid flow v
$$\frac{d}{dt}\iiint_{G} \rho \vec{V} dv = \iiint_{G}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \rho \vec{V} dv + \iint_{S} [\rho\vec{v}]\vec{v} \cdot \hat n ds $$

The second term on the right hand side reduces to:

$$\iint [\rho v_{x} \vec{v}]\cdot \hat n ds\hat i
+\iint [\rho v_{y} \vec{v}]\cdot \hat n ds\hat j
+\iint [\rho v_{z} \vec{v}]\cdot \hat n ds\hat k$$

Applying the divergence theorem

$$\iiint \nabla \cdot [ v_{x} \rho\vec{v}]\hat idv +
\iiint \nabla \cdot [ v_{y} \rho\vec{v}]\hat jdv +
\iiint \nabla \cdot [ v_{y} \rho\vec{v}]\hat kdv $$

$$\iiint (\nabla \cdot [ v_{x} \rho\vec{v}]\hat i +
 \nabla \cdot [ v_{y} \rho\vec{v}]\hat j +
 \nabla \cdot [ v_{y} \rho\vec{v}]\hat k)dv $$

Using a vector identity on the integrals, we see that $$\nabla \cdot [ v_{x} \rho\vec{v}] = v_{x} \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec{v}) + \rho \nabla v_{x} \cdot \vec{v}$$
$$\nabla \cdot [ v_{y} \rho\vec{v}] = v_{y} \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec{v}) + \rho \nabla v_{y} \cdot \vec{v}$$

$$\nabla \cdot [ v_{z} \rho\vec{v}] = v_{z} \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec{v}) + \rho \nabla v_{z} \cdot \vec{v}$$

Meaning in vector form we obtain that the integrand of  surface part of the integral is just

$$\vec{V}\nabla \cdot [\rho\vec{V}] + \rho (\vec{V} \cdot \nabla)\vec{V}$$

And hence:

$$\iint_{S} [\rho\vec{v}]\vec{v} \cdot \hat n ds = \iiint_{G}\vec{V}\nabla \cdot [\rho\vec{V}] + \rho (\vec{V} \cdot \nabla)\vec{V} dv $$

Now let's focus in the left integral on the right hand side:

$$\iiint_{G}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \rho \vec{V} dv = \iiint [\rho \frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial t} + \vec{V}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}] dv$$

Combining the two we obtain

$$\frac{d}{dt}\iiint_{G} \rho \vec{V} dv = \iiint_{G} \rho \frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial t} + \vec{V}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} +\vec{V}\nabla \cdot [\rho\vec{V}] + \rho (\vec{V} \cdot \nabla)\vec{V} dv $$

Using the continuity equation
$$\nabla \cdot [\rho\vec{V}] = -\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}$$
And simplifying:

$$\iiint_{G} \rho \frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial t}  + \rho (\vec{V} \cdot \nabla)\vec{V} dv $$

$$\iiint_{G} \rho [\frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial t}  + (\vec{V} \cdot \nabla)\vec{V}] dv $$

Envoking the definition of the material derivative

$$\iiint_{G} \rho \frac{D \vec{V}}{D t}dv $$